# C: Heap Buffer Overflow when Storing Elements Using Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, string, dynamic, malloc, buffer-overflow

I am writing a C program to store and then print out all strings given through stdin using dynamic memory allocation.
It prompts the user for input until it reads "end of file" (EOF, ctrl + d).
I am assuming that no line is longer than 255 characters.

I am relatively new to coding in C, and also new to using the malloc() function, so please bear with me if I am making some obvious, rookie mistake. Please offer advice and help me fix my program. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER 255

int main(void) 
{
    
    char line[BUFFER];
    int item = 0;
    char** data = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("Enter string %d: ", item + 1);

        if (fgets(line, BUFFER, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            fgets(line, BUFFER, stdin);
        }

        data = realloc(data, sizeof(void *) * (item + 1));
        data[item] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(line));
        memcpy(data[item], line, strlen(line));

        item++;

    }
    
    printf("\n\nElements:\n");
    
    for(int j = 0; j < item; j++)
    {
        printf("%s",data[j]);

        free(data[j]);
    }

    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

The first concern I have is that my program prompts the user twice to enter a string input per `item` increment. This is not supposed to happen, and should continually ask the user while updating `item`'s count.

Also, my program does not store the strings entered correctly; it returns a buffer overflow message when attempting to access and print my stored strings. I have never seen an error quite like it before:

==20==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000052 at pc 0x55a8453c7865 bp 0x7ffd578edac0 sp 0x7ffd578ed280
READ of size 3 at 0x602000000052 thread T0
#0 0x55a8453c7864 in printf_common(void*, char const*, __va_list_tag*) asan_interceptors.cpp.o
#1 0x55a8453c819a in __interceptor_vprintf (/home/run+0xb119a) (BuildId: abfaad925a09237bc199a1c2ac9a7d328268e42f)
#2 0x55a8453c8277 in printf (/home/run+0xb1277) (BuildId: abfaad925a09237bc199a1c2ac9a7d328268e42f)
#3 0x55a84543014d in main /home/main.c:39:9
#4 0x7f08c84fe28f in __libc_start_call_main /usr/src/debug/glibc/csu/../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:16
#5 0x7f08c84fe349 in __libc_start_main /usr/src/debug/glibc/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:381:3
#6 0x55a845337084 in _start /build/glibc/src/glibc/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:115

Comment: @user3121023 I have changed this line and the problem persists. Thank-you for pointing it out, though!

Comment: @Akiyuu You *also* need to terminate the string.  `data[item] = malloc(sizeof(char) * ( strlen(line) + 1));` is insufficient.  Replace `memcpy()` with `strcpy()`.

Comment: @user3121023 these two changes actually fixed my code altogether! Thank-you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

`getline` is useful when the length of the longest line is unknown. It will allocate memory as needed. It also returns the number of characters processed.
It is good to reallocate to a temporary pointer. If `realloc` fails, the original pointer is still valid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {

    char *line;
    size_t size = 0;
    ssize_t length = 0;
    int item = 0;
    char** data = NULL;

    for ( ; ; ) {
        printf ( "Enter string %d: ", item + 1);
        fflush ( stdout);

        if ( 0 > ( length = getline ( &line, &size, stdin))) {
            break;
        }

        char **temp = NULL;
        if ( NULL == ( temp = realloc ( data, sizeof *data * (item + 1)))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "realloc problem\n");
            break;
        }
        data = temp;
        if ( NULL == ( data[item] = malloc ( sizeof **data * ( length + 1)))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "malloc problem\n");
            break;
        }

        strcpy ( data[item], line);

        item++;
    }

    free ( line);

    printf("\n\nElements:\n");

    for(int j = 0; j < item; j++) {
        if ( data[j] && data[j][0]) { // not NULL and not zero
            printf ( "%s", data[j]);
        }
        free(data[j]);
    }
    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```